# Add the last index of an array with a unique seperator

Tags: arrays, ruby, join, flatten

I am trying to get the last character of an array to join with it's own character. I'm having trouble trying to figure this out on my own I'm still unfamiliar with built in methods on ruby.  Here's where I'm at so far:

```
def list(names)
#last = names.last
joined = names.map(&:values).flatten.join(", ")
#joined.pop
#joined << last.join(" &")
end
```

What I want to do is for the last index I want to join it with it's own character.  I've tried doing this for hours but I keep getting errors.  If anyone can point me in the right direction on this I would greatly appreciate it.

My target goal for an output would be

```
list([{name: 'Bart'},{name: 'Lisa'},{name: 'Garry'}])
```

to output:

```
"Bart, Lisa & Gary"
```

Comment: Could you please add an example of input and expected output?

Comment: I just did sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with the Oxford comma, which I prefer :)

```
def list(name_list)
  *names, last = name_list.flat_map(&:values)
  oxford_comma = names.size > 1 ? ", " : ""
  names.join(", ") + oxford_comma + "& #{last}"
end
```

(Note: if this is Rails, `Array#to_sentence` does this automatically.)

Comment: You could replace map + flatten with flat_map

Comment: I added the `flat_map`. Good point about the Oxford comma. I assumed it wouldn't actually be used by OP though :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that yields your desired output, given your input:

```
def list(names)
    *head, tail = names.map(&:values)
    [head.join(", "), tail].join(" & ")
end
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Note that you could use `map` rather than `flat_map`, as [Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-join) is applied recursively.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the tip!  I've edited my answer to reflect your feedback.  I guess I should read the docs a little more carefully.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating the string with all names separated by commas (e.g., "Bart, Lisa, Garry") and then replacing the last comma with " &". Here are two ways to do that.

**Code**

```
def list1(names)
  all_commas(names).tap { |s| s[s.rindex(',')] = ' &' }
end

def list2(names)
  all_commas(names).sub(/,(?=[^,]+\z)/, ' &')
end

def all_commas(names)
  names.map(&:values).join(', ')
end
```

**Example**

```
names = [{ name: 'Bart' }, { name: 'Lisa' } , { name: 'Garry' }]

list1 names
  #=> "Bart, Lisa & Garry"

list2 names
  #=> "Bart, Lisa & Garry"
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows.

*For `all_commas`:*

```
a = names.map(&:values)
  #=> [["Bart"], ["Lisa"], ["Garry"]]
a.join(', ')
  #=> "Bart, Lisa, Garry"
```

*For `list1`*

```
s = all_commas(names)
  #=> "Bart, Lisa, Garry"
i = s.rindex(',')
  #=> 10
s[i] = ' &'
  #=> " &"
s #=> "Bart, Lisa & Garry"
```

`tap`'s block returns `s`

*For `list2`*

```
a = all_commas(names)
  #=> "Bart, Lisa, Garry"
a.sub(/,(?=[^,]+\z)/, ' &')
  # => "Bart, Lisa & Garry"
```

The regular expression, which employs a *positive lookahead*, reads, "match a comma, followed by one or more characters other than comma, followed by the end of the string".